# Reverting Laravel Packages

Tags: git, composer-php, laravel-5.1

I updated my laravel packages using composer and committed and pushed the vendor file, composer.json and composer.lock to live. Now I get error 500 on live site. Is there a way I can revert the changes on the live environment?

Comment: Rather than just rolling it back, why don't you just see why you are getting the error and check your logs. Assuming you are running apache as your web server in a linux environment, run `sudo tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log` and see what it shows - if you need to reload the page you got a 500 error on and it will show you why in the console

Answer (score 0):

Try `git reset --hard` will bring you to the last commit

eg: your commits are as follows

```
10 // currently you are there,
9 // git reset --hard will bring you there
8
...
```

**The reason of error can be**

you uploaded composer.json/.lock file, but it seems you didn't run `composer update`  commands on live server, run `composer update` and then composer dump-autoload and then `php artisan cache:clear` then `php artisan config:clear` I hope it will solve the issue